# How do I resolve a Thymeleaf template to send in an email?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am setting up email verification in a Spring Boot project of mine. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email) from baeldung. I want to send an HTML email using a Thymeleaf template. After looking around the internet, I decided to autowire a `SpringTemplateEngine` instance for my `RegistrationListener` and use it to process the template:

```
Context context = new Context(event.getLocale());
context.setVariable("token", token);

String html = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process("account/verify_email", context);
```

This method, however, is not working because my template references relative resources:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/webjars/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "account/verify_email" - line 3, col 7)
```

Looking at the exception message, I decided to explore classes implementing `IWebContext`. The best match was `WebContext`. However, I cannot simply create a WebContext instance because it requires `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, and `ServletContext` parameters for the [constructor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.BETA01/org/thymeleaf/context/WebContext.html#WebContext-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-javax.servlet.ServletContext-). These are objects which would be accessible in my controller, but not in my event listener.

Is it possible to process my Thymeleaf template in an event listener?

Comment: Here's the thing.  Relative references like that don't work in emails.  The gmail servers aren't going to contain a copy of `bootstrap.min.css` that you emails can reference with a relative link.  Your must get rid of those references.  Either include the css directly in the file (in <style> tags), remove them, or change them to absolute URLs.

Comment: @Metroids following your advice with a little help from https://bootstrapemail.com/, I was able to get the desired result. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative references like `/webjars/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` simply don't work in emails (because the emails are not located on the originating server, a relative css reference doesn't make sense).  In cases like this, your options (after removing the relative links) are:

1. Include the css inline:

   ```
    <style>
    /* Put the contents of /webjars/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css  here */
    </style>
   ```
2. Just modify the tags directly with inline css:

   ```
    <div style="font-family: sans-serif; color:#666666;>Your content here.../div>
   ```
3. Change the link to an absolute URL (which may or may not work because some clients remove these references).

   ```
    <style href="https://yourserver/webjars/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   ```